# How to sort results from an IndexedDB query?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Is it possible to receive sorted results from an IndexedDB query?  If not, what is the best way to go about sorting results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get items sorted by the object store's key or any index's order using IDBObjectStore.openCursor, IDBIndex.openCursor, and IDBIndex.openKeyCursor.

Note that with the speed implementations are moving, it's probably a good idea to use http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/IndexedDB/raw-file/tip/Overview.html

Comment: I can't see any obvious comments in the spec about the ordering, only about the range.

Comment: @DanielGerson https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#cursor-construct section "2.10 Cursor" says that it sets the direction of fetching the records, e.g. for "prev": `This direction causes the cursor to be opened at the end of the source. When iterated, the cursor should yield all records, including duplicates, in monotonically decreasing order of keys.`

Comment: However if you asked about other sorting than the "default" key sort ASC/DESC, then I'm afraid that's not possible (yet). Alternatively, you could create a special index for autogenerated key that would add some "weight" based on e.g. a string and sort according to that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a range on an index.  Read more here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBObjectStore-openCursor